# How do you change 'write_options' in prolog to print a long list?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

By default, SICStus Prolog will only display the first ten elements of a list (after which it shows `...`).

How do you make Prolog display all the elements of a long list? I have tried:

```
set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options,
    [quoted(true), portray(true), max_depth(100), priority(699)]).
```

but I get the message

```
expected write_option, but found portray(true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the option `portray` is invalid, it should be `portrayed`.

I think this will do:

```
set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options,
    [quoted(true), portrayed(true), max_depth(0)]).
```

with `max_depth(0)` being no limit, that is what I guess you are looking for.